# transform property using map failed got unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have nested array of object structure look like this

```
const resp = [
  [
    {
      id: 1
      "name": {
        "en": {
          "language": "en",
          "value": "something"
        },
        "id": {
          "language": "th",
          "value": "something else"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

I use ES6 to truncate the name property, base on 'en':

```
resp = resp.map(o => ({
      ...o,
      o.map(o2 => ({ //unexpected token
        ...o2,
        name: o2.name.en.value
      })
    )
  })
)
```

But I got the unexpected token error?

I want to produce this result

```
//expected output
const resp = [
  [
    {
      id: 1
      name: "something"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: node.js version?

Comment: and what was the unexpected token? post the complete stack trace

Answer (score 1):

```js
const resp = [
    [{
        id: 1,
        "name": {
            "en": {
                "language": "en",
                "value": "something"
            },
            "id": {
                "language": "th",
                "value": "something else"
            }
        }
    }]
];

const result = resp.map(o => {
    return o.map(o2 => {
        return {
            id: o2.id,
            name: o2.name.en.value
        }
    })
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: why no ...o in the first map? what if there are properties in the first level of array? can you use `{}` and `return` for better readability?

Comment: what do you mean by `what if there are properties in the first level of array?`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using `Array.reduce()` function, other than using `Array.map()` as @AushGupta has answer. The detailed description and answers are at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const resp = [
          [
              {
                  id: 1,
                  "name": {
                      "en": {
                          "language": "en",
                          "value": "something"
                      },
                      "id": {
                          "language": "th",
                          "value": "something else"
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                  id: 3,
                  "name": {
                      "en": {
                          "language": "en",
                          "value": "newthing"
                      },
                      "id": {
                          "language": "th",
                          "value": "something else"
                      }
                  }
              }
          ],
          [
              {
                  id: 2,
                  "name": {
                      "en": {
                          "language": "en",
                          "value": "something"
                      },
                      "id": {
                          "language": "th",
                          "value": "something else"
                      }
                  }
              }
          ]
      ];
   var result = resp.reduce((results, current) => {
          var items = current.reduce((items, item) => {
              items.push({
                  id: item.id,
                  name: item.name.en.value
              });
              return items;
          }, []);
          results.push(items);
          return results;
      }, []);
      console.log(result);
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are just replicating what map does with those reduce

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. This `Array.reduce()` also serves the purpose here. But here how it works is explained for user. That is why it makes sense to write separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map` on the `array` and you just need to return an object with id and name.

```js
const resp = [
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      "name": {
        "en": {
          "language": "en",
          "value": "something"
        },
        "id": {
          "language": "th",
          "value": "something else"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
];

let result = resp[0].map(
  el => {return {"id": el.id, "name": el.name.en.value}}
);

console.log(result);
```

You might need to wrap result in another array.

Comment: The above will only work on the first element of the `resp` array, and will throw an error if `resp` is empty

Comment: @AyushGupta you might have missed that this array is inside another array. `const resp = [ [`. And I have already mentioned that he might need to do a little modification as his element has just one element.

Comment: What I am saying, is that if `resp` has two elements, 2 internal arrays if you will, `result` will contain the transformed state of the first internal array.

Comment: and if `resp` is empty, `resp[0]` will be undefined, so `cannot read property map of undefined`. Just a few edge cases.

Comment: resp[0] doesn't make sense here, I didn't mock more data to simplify my question.